# Why I can't connect to github via ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, github

I've searched a lot and all found solutions weren't work.

I generated ssh key via:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "myemail@gmail.com"
```

I got the key:

```
cat /home/drupality/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

I noticed that key hasn't an email address inside, but my username (drupality).

I put key to github SSH keys settings.

Most imported:

```
ssh-add /home/drupality/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Now I'm trying:

```
ssh git@github.com
```

an output:

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.130)' can't be
established. RSA key fingerprint is
16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48. Are you sure you want
to continue connecting (yes/no)?  Host key verification failed.
```

What I've done wrong?

Comment: why do you put `-T` there? You need to verify host key and it should prompt you for it and write some more verbose info

Comment: @Jakuje do you mean ssh -T git@github.com? without -T I got identical output.

Comment: You forgot to type `yes` at the prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really nice how-to on github:

https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-github-s-ssh-key-fingerprints/

Your keys fingerprint is matching so no worry with writing `yes` and pressing enter.